# What is the right way to ask

Tags: word-usage

If you want to rent your apartment, what is the proper way to say so? Do you offer a friend an apartment in rent?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking what would be an acceptable wording for a statement offering an apartment for rent, here is my suggestion:

"I have an apartment for rent. Are you interested?"

Or if the statement will be used for an online or written advertisement, I suggest simply:
"Apartment for rent:" followed by the terms of rental, such as the amount of the rental fee, whether or not utilities are included, and the size of the apartment and number of bedrooms/bathrooms.

As for your question regarding whether you can offer a friend an apartment that you have for rent, whether or not it is appropriate depends entirely on the situation and what your friendship is like. I would say that if you have an apartment for rent and you have a friend that is looking for an apartment, it is usually appropriate to simply notify that friend in a statement similar to the one I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

*X rents Y* - X is staying at Y and paying rent to the owner of Y (X is the tenant).

*X rents out Y [to Z]* - X owns Y and is letting Z stay there if Z pays rent (Z is the tenant).

*X rents Y to Z* - Same as *X rents out Y to Z*.

*X is for rent* - The owner of X is looking for a tenant.

*X is renting [out Y] for Z* - The owner of X is looking for a tenant that will pay *Z* if Z is a cost, or the owner of X is seeking a tenant on behalf of Z if Z is person.  Y would be the place itself if specified.

If you want to let your friend stay somewhere in exchange for money, you are *renting* or *renting out* a place to him.

Answer (score 0):

> A renter rents 'from' a landlord.  I rent my apartment from Mr. Biggs.

> A landlord rents 'to' a renter.  I rented [leased] 210 Elm St. to Mary J.

> An apartment that is on the market to be rented is 'for' rent.  201 Elm St. is for rent.